# Jquery: How to dynamically bind a textbox with onload event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A `textbox` is created on runtime in Javascript. It gets open when user clicks a `button`.

```
<input type="text" id="documentTitle" name="documentTitle" value="<spring:message code="document.Title"/>"
```

On click I want to display `textbox` text highlighted.

How to fire onload element using JQuery?

Tried following JQuery, but not successful:

```
$(document).on("load", "#documentTitle" , function() {
        myquery.highlightText(this);
});
```

Comment: u need to show textarea on click and its text should be highlighted  right ?

Comment: You can use the `focus` event

Comment: Could you try giving some more details to your problem ? and put a little more of your code ?

Comment: @Lulylulu
Just did bit editing. I am unable to fire onload event on dynamically created textbox element using above

Comment: The `load` event only fires on elements that get their contents from external data, e.g. `<img>` fires the `load` event when the image is downloaded.

Comment: @ArunPJohny

Just did bit editing. I am unable to fire onload event on dynamically created textbox element using above

Comment: What is `#documentTitle`?

Comment: @Barmar
It is ID of dynamically created textbox

Comment: @fatherazrael Why do you want to use the onload event ? If you are creating the textbox when the user clicks on a button, then you can add the highlighttext code in that event listener itself right ?

Comment: A textbox doesn't have a `load` event.

Comment: There is no `load` event for input

Comment: you have to do it with your button click event, which generate the text box.

Comment: Then how to achieve the same?

Comment: Is there any other method instead of changing button click?

Comment: Without over-complicating things - no.

Answer (score 1):

i don't what you exactly want but here some code that may help you ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("on load event fire");
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("textarea").show();
  })
});
```

```css
textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea style="display:none">asdasdasd</textarea>
<button>
  show
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont have the choice there is no event fired when an arbitrary DOM element such as a `<div>` becomes ready.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $(document).on("click", "#test", function() {
            $("#content").append('<input type="text" id="documentTitle" name="documentTitle" value=""/>');
            
            //do your highlight here
            $("#content #documentTitle").val("test");
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="test" value="test" />
<div id="content"></div>
```

If you really want an event you should create a custom one

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(document).on("click", "#test", function() {
        $("#content").append('<input type="text" id="documentTitle" name="documentTitle" value=""/>');           
        $("#content #documentTitle").trigger("myLoadedevent");
    });

    $(document).on("myLoadedevent", "#documentTitle", function() {
        //do your highlight here
        alert('event');
    });

});
```